# "AttributeError: Layer cnn_model has no inbound nodes" when making a model from a subclassed model for Keras GradCam tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to follow this [GradCam Tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) with my own model. Here is its architecture:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
import numpy as np

class CNNModel(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.base = K.applications.EfficientNetB1(input_shape=(224, 224, 12),
                                                  include_top=False,
                                                  weights=None)

        self.pool = K.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.drop1 = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dense1 = K.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.drop2 = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.base(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.drop2(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

model = CNNModel()
model.build(input_shape=(None, 224, 224, 12))
```

I need to get the last convolutional layer, so I'm getting the one from the base (**EfficientNet**) model:

```
last_conv_layer_name = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D), model.base.layers))[-1].name
```

Then I'm trying to make a 2 output model based on that, just like in the tutorial.

```
grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.base.inputs], [model.base.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )
```

I'm getting:

> AttributeError: Layer cnn_model has no inbound nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue regarding the subclassed API model and further trying to use it in **grad-cam** by incorporating it into functional API. Later, the thing that worked for me that time was to build a subclassed model separately for grad-cam either and build desired output model in `__init__`.

```
class CNNModel(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.base = K.applications.EfficientNetB1(input_shape=(224, 224, 12),
                                                  include_top=False,
                                                  weights=None)
        # desired model 
        self.base = K.Model(
                [self.base.inputs], 
                [self.base.get_layer('top_conv').output, self.base.output]
            )

        self.pool = K.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.drop1 = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dense1 = K.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.drop2 = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.base(x)
        top_conv = x[0]
        x = x[1] 
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.drop2(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return top_conv, x

model = CNNModel()
model.build(input_shape=(None, 224, 224, 12))
```

Passing some data to check.

```
img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 12).astype(np.float32)
(convOutputs, predictions) = model(img_array)
print(convOutputs.shape, predictions.shape)
(1, 7, 7, 1280) (1, 1)
```

Comment: ` model.layers[-1].output` gives:

`AttributeError: Layer dense_1 has no inbound nodes.`

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69788850/9215780