# Tensorflow 2: No Longer Able to Track Attributes of a Subclassed Model After Loaded

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

Here is my implementation of a Subclassed Model in Tensorflow 2.5:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet201
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.random import uniform
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model 

class Detector(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, num_classes=3, name="DenseNet201"):
        super(Detector, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.feature_extractor = DenseNet201(
            include_top=False,
            weights="imagenet",
        )
        self.feature_extractor.trainable = False
        self.flatten_layer = Flatten()
        self.prediction_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation=None)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = preprocess_input(inputs)
        self.extracted_feature = self.feature_extractor(x, training=False)
        x = self.flatten_layer(self.extracted_feature)
        x = self.prediction_layer(x)
        return x
```

While testing my code, I found something that really confused me.

```
detector = Detector()
print(detector.extracted_feature)
```

This gives me an error: AttributeError: 'Detector' object has no attribute 'extracted_feature', which is understandable since I have never called the model in the first place. After calling the model, `Detector` object now has the attribute `extracted_feature`. So the following code will execute without any error:

```
image_tensor_1 = uniform(shape=(1, 600, 600, 3))
y_hat = detector(image_tensor_1)
print(detector.extracted_feature.shape)
```

However, after trying to save the model by running `detector.save("my_model")` and load the model back to a new variable `new_detector = load_model("my_model")`. I got an error running the code below:

```
image_tensor_2 = uniform(shape=(1, 600, 600, 3))
y_hat = new_detector(image_tensor_2)
print(new_detector.extracted_feature.shape)
```

**AttributeError: 'Detector' object has no attribute 'extracted_feature'.**

`self.extracted_feature` is what I use to calculate the gradient. I need to keep tracking it so the gradient will not be `None`. What should I do to access the attribute `extracted_feature`?

Comment: The `self...` in the `call` function won't save with the model, things need to be initiated in the `init` method. Apart from that, do you need the output feature maps from your base model? If so, why not just init your model in that way?

Comment: @M.Innat I do need the output feature maps from my base model in order to calculate gradients.  I added `self,extracted_feature = None` in the `init` method and hoped to modify `self.featured_feature` later in the `call` method but it was of no use. Could you please elaborate your point since I am just beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = preprocess_input(inputs)
        extracted_feature = self.feature_extractor(x, training=False)
        x = self.flatten_layer(extracted_feature)
        x = self.prediction_layer(x)
        return extracted_feature, x
```

Checking

```
image_tensor_1 = uniform(shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))
detector = Detector()
ex_feat, y_hat = detector(image_tensor_1)
print(ex_feat.shape)
(1, 1, 1, 512)
```

Save and reload.

```
detector.save("my_model")
new_detector = load_model("my_model")

image_tensor_2 = uniform(shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))
ex_feat, y_hat = new_detector(image_tensor_2)
print(ex_feat.shape)
(1, 1, 1, 512)
```

FYI, if you want to get intermediate layer output from the base model, then you may need to init your base model in that way in the `__init__` method.

Comment: I have tried this before but I gave up this approach because `detector.fit()` will throw an error. I had little experience in custom training,

Comment: This is the general approach. Could you please include the error you face with .fit by using the above approach?

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [64,18,18] vs. [64,1]
  [[node Equal (defined at <ipython-input-7-1c9d4b49ca66>:19) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_32187]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: I guess this will confuse the training process because it does not know whether to fit on the `extracted_feature` or the final output of `x`, which is the prediction. By the way I am using `ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: It can be sovled. But do you need this base feature for inference time or training time?

Comment: Inference, since I am using it to make heatmaps in GradCAM.

Comment: I see, so in that case, you should first train your model normally then save its weights (not the whole model) and build your subclass model with the appropriate output layer in inference time. This should solve your further issue.  Check this for more details regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608627/9215780

Comment: I tried but with no luck. I think it's necessary to pose another question because this is another issue regarding `call` method and `model.fit`. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Thanks. If this answer solves your above question, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Definitely . I will go through the code you provided bit by bit tonight.