# Tensorflow 2: How to fit a subclassed model that returns multiple values in the call method?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I built the following model via Model Subclassing in TensorFlow 2:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet201
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

class Detector(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, num_classes=3, name="DenseNet201"):
        super(Detector, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.feature_extractor = DenseNet201(
            include_top=False,
            weights="imagenet",
        )
        self.feature_extractor.trainable = False
        self.flatten_layer = Flatten()
        self.prediction_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation=None)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = preprocess_input(inputs)
        extracted_feature = self.feature_extractor(x, training=False)
        x = self.flatten_layer(extracted_feature)
        y_hat = self.prediction_layer(x)
        return extracted_feature, y_hat
```

The subsequent steps are compiling and fitting the model. The model compiled as normal but when fitting my image generator (built from `ImageDataGenerator`), I encountered the error: InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64,18,18] vs. [64,1] [[node Equal (defined at :19) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_32187] Function call stack: train_function –.

```
history = detector.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=1,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

This is obvious because TensorFlow does not know whether the prediction is `y_hat` or `extracted_feature`during `detector.fit()` and thus threw an error. So, what is the right implementation of `detector.fit` for my case?

Comment: Why do you want to return ```extracted_feature``` from your model ? The shapes output from the generator must must match the model inputs and targets (i.e. the output of the call method).

Comment: As I said, in training time, you train the model normally, which means the output should be the only x. But in inference time we can modify with more than one output.

Comment: @Pedro Marques I want to plot GradCAMs so accessing extracted feature is crucial for visualization.

Comment: @M.Innat If I don't have extracted feature returned in the call method. How can I access it in the inference phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67898254/9215780)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67898254/9215780), you should first train your model with (let's say) one input and one output. And later if you want to compute grad-cam, you would pick some **intermediate layer** of your base model (not the final output of the base model) and in that case, you need to build your feature extractor separately. For example

```
# (let's say: one input and one output)
# use for training 
base_model = keras.application(...)
x = base_model(..)
dese_drop_bn_[whatever] = x
out = dese_drop_bn_[whatever]
model = Model(base_model.input, out) 

# inference / we need to compute grad cam 
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(model.input, 
                       [model.layers[15].output, model.output])
```

In the above, the `model` is used for training, and later in inference time if you need to compute grad-cam based on the layer for example layer number 15, you need to build `new_model` with appropriate outputs. Hope this makes things clear. For more information about feature extraction, see the official doc, [Extract and reuse nodes in the graph of layers](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/)[2](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/). FYI, the exact same things are happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608627/9215780) as I informed you earlier. Also, check this [official code example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/), you will see exact same thing there.

---

However, there is another way that I'm thinking might work for your easily. That is, as you're using a custom model, we can take the privilege `training` argument in the `call()` method. Normally in training time, this is `True` and for inference time it's `False`. So, based on this, we can return desired output the accordingly. Here is the complete code example:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# get some data
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
   'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.20)
dataflow_kwargs = dict(target_size=(64, 64),
                       batch_size=16,
                       interpolation="bilinear")

train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rotation_range=40,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
      **datagen_kwargs)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir, subset="training", shuffle=True, **dataflow_kwargs)
```

```
for image, label in train_generator:
    print(image.shape, image.dtype)
    print(label.shape, label.dtype)
    print(label[:4])
    break

(16, 64, 64, 3) float32
(16, 5) float32
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Here we do that trick based on the boolean value of `training` in the `call` method.

```
class Detector(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=5, name="DenseNet201"):
        super(Detector, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.feature_extractor = DenseNet201(
            include_top=False,
            weights="imagenet",
        )

        self.feature_extractor.trainable = False
        self.flatten_layer = Flatten()
        self.prediction_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        x = preprocess_input(inputs)
        extracted_feature = self.feature_extractor(x, training=False)
        x = self.flatten_layer(extracted_feature)
        y_hat = self.prediction_layer(x)

        if training:
            return y_hat 
        else:
            return [y_hat, extracted_feature]
```

**Train**

```
det = Detector()
det.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
            optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

train_step = train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size

det.fit(train_generator, 
      steps_per_epoch=train_step,
      validation_data=train_generator, 
      validation_steps=train_step,
      epochs=2, verbose=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/2
37s 139ms/step - loss: 1.7543 - acc: 0.2650 - val_loss: 1.5310 - val_acc: 0.3764
Epoch 2/2
21s 115ms/step - loss: 1.4913 - acc: 0.3915 - val_loss: 1.3066 - val_acc: 0.4667
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa2890b1790>
```

**Evaluate**

```
det.evaluate(train_generator, 
      steps=train_step)

4s 76ms/step - loss: 1.3066 - acc: 0.4667
[1.3065541982650757, 0.46666666865348816]
```

**Inference**

Here, we will get two outputs of this model (unlike 1 output that we've got in the training time).

```
y_hat, base_feature = det.predict(train_generator, 
                        steps=train_step)

y_hat.shape, base_feature.shape
((720, 5), (720, 2, 2, 1920))
```

Now, you can do grad-cam or whatever require such feature maps.

Comment: Thanks, a lot to learn. `training` seemed to be a parameter that I don't need to explicitly modify as it can change with the state of the model. When calling `model.predict(X)` `training` should be False and when calling `model.fit()` `training` should be True. What about case like `model(inputs)`?

Comment: Sorry, what about? Normally `model(input)` runs in inference mode. But you can make this explicit: `model(inputs, training=True)`  for training mode and `model(input, training = False)` for inference mode.

Comment: I see. Thank you again for your time, I will continue to test my code to see whether it works as expected.

Comment: I revised my code. It seems that the `new_model` loaded from the directory created by `old_model.save()` is able to capture extracted feature but failed to calculate the gradient. Inside the context manger of `GradientTape()`, 'grads = tape.gradient(loss, extracted_feature)' gave me `grads` of `None`. I tried many different approaches previously because I wanted to avoid `grads` being `None`. I found that `model.save()` and `load_model` will lose track of gradient. What's your take on this? I will do more research tomorrow to configure it out.

Comment: Sorry, it was midnight here. May I ask if the issue solved?

Comment: For this particular question, yes. I am able to to make GradCAMs. However, if I save the model to a new directory. Restart my Jupyter Kernel and load a new model from the directory. I am no longer able to make GradCAMs. The reason is because `tape.gradient(loss, exracted_feature)` returns `None`. This won't happen if the model is a freshly trained model (rather than a loaded model). Right when you were asking, I was compiling another question on Stackoverflow. Seems that other similar posts on the platform are not able to solve this problem.