# Get the output of the last convolutional layer of a pre-trained architecture in subclassed Keras model for gradcam

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to get the output of the final convolutional layer of a pre-trained model. I need it to calculate the grad-cam. In order to do this, I need to make a model that has two outputs, one classification, and the output of the convolutional layer, like in this [tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/). It's not working. It says:

> AttributeError: Layer custom_mobile_net_3 has no inbound nodes.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
import numpy as np

height, width, channels = 224, 224, 3

class CustomMobileNet(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMobileNet, self).__init__()
        self.base = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(height, width, channels),
                                               include_top=True,
                                               weights=None)
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.base(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

model = CustomMobileNet()

last_conv_layer_name = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, 
                       K.layers.Conv2D), model.base.layers))[-1].name

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [model.base.inputs], 
        [model.base.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output,
                              model.output]
    ) # PROBLEM

img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3).astype(np.float32)
pred_index = None

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
    if pred_index is None:
        pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
```

**Changing the model definition is not an option.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you need, we can do something like as follows.

**Trainable Model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
import numpy as np
height, width, channels = 224, 224, 3

class CustomMobileNet(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMobileNet, self).__init__()
        self.base = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(height, width, channels),
                                               include_top=True,
                                               weights=None)
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.base(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

model = CustomMobileNet()
last_conv_layer_name = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, 
                                                        K.layers.Conv2D), 
                                   model.base.layers))[-1].name
```

**Grad-CAM Model**

```
class GradCustomMobileNet(CustomMobileNet): # or, K.Model
    def __init__(self):
        super(GradCustomMobileNet, self).__init__()
        self.base = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(height, width, channels),
                                               include_top=True,
                                               weights=None)
        
        self.base = tf.keras.models.Model(
            [self.base.inputs], 
            [self.base.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output,
                       self.base.output]
        )
        
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        conv, x = self.base(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return conv, x

grad_model = GradCustomMobileNet()
```

**Compute Gradient**

```
img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3).astype(np.float32)
pred_index = None

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
    if pred_index is None:
        pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
grads.shape
TensorShape([1, 7, 7, 1280])
```

Comment: It seems like .get_layer and .output command is for functional model. Can I apply Grad-CAM with a pure sunclassed model?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute **GradCAM** from a subclassed API model, I think the following is more cleaner and concise compared to my old answer. We can take leverage the `training` argument of the `call` method of the subclassed model. In this way, we don't need to build any new class model separately for **GradCAM**. Here is how.

---

```
height, width, channels = 224, 224, 3

class CustomMobileNet(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMobileNet, self).__init__()
        base = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(height, width, channels),
                                          include_top=False,
                                          weights='imagenet')
        
        last_conv_layer_name = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,
                        K.layers.Conv2D), 
                  base.layers))[-1].name # or set any layer name manually
                                         
        self.base = K.Model(
            [base.inputs], 
            [base.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, base.output]
        )
        self.gap = K.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.out = K.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        conv, x = self.base(x)
        x = self.gap(x)
        x = self.out(x)

        if training: # TRUE for model.fit 
            return x 
        else: # TRUE for model.predict
            return conv, x
```

Now, we can do training normally, i.e. `model. fit`. However, note, while building the above model, we must build the `self.base` model in such way. I mean,

```
K.Model(
         [base.inputs], 
         [base.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, 
          base.output]
        )
```

Next, in prediction time, we do simply as follows:

```
model = CustomMobileNet()
img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3).astype(np.float32)

pred_index = None
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    last_conv_layer_output, preds = model(img_array)

    if pred_index is None:
        pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
grads.shape
TensorShape([1, 7, 7, 1280])
```